# Trouble Installing SimpleCV

Tags: python, eclipse, windows-7, opencv, simplecv

I am trying to install SimpleCV on Windows 7 with Eclipse Indigo. I used the superpack-installer with Python, Numpy etc. Everything works fine except for SimpleCV, when I try to import SimpleCV I get the following error output:

import SimpleCV

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\SimpleCV_init.py", line 3, in  # $Id$ File "build\bdist.win32\egg\SimpleCV\base.py", line 31, in  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial_init.py", line 25, in  from kdtree import * File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\kdtree.py", line 6, in  import scipy.sparse File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse_init_.py", line 182, in  from csgraph import * AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'csgraph_to_masked'

Did something go wrong during the installation process? I can't find any help on "csgraph_to_masked" on the internet.  (In fact, searching for "simplecv csgraph_to_masked" didn't return a single search result)  SimpleCV is proclaimed to be very easy to install, so I was a little surprised when I ran into issues so early.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears to be coming from scipy.

You could try just re-installing scipy to see if that fixes anything, or just re-install simplecv from scratch.

You can head here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.10.1/

Just make sure to grab for python 2.7

Comment: I figured this might be the problem.  I ended up replacing the Scipy in the SimpleCV installer with the most recent (stable) version of Scipy, and that fixed the problem.