# numpy error when trying to install and run simplecv on OSX

Tags: python, numpy, simplecv

*I realize trying to remotely diagnose and resolve install issues (esp. with Python) is difficult if not futile but I've exhausted all the web suggestions I've found.*

**OS**: OSX 10.8.5

The gist is that I installed everything through Homebrew and am getting the same error as [this person on the simplecv site](https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/issues/577) Full error output is below.

> ImportError: cannot import name add_newdocs

I've been through the install guides from simplecv and those linked from that site and I have seen these questions: [How to install SimpleCV on OSX 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294242/how-to-install-simplecv-on-osx-10-8) and [Trouble Installing SimpleCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204339/trouble-installing-simplecv) but no luck trying their solutions. I've tried various other ways of installing scipy, numpy, etc.

In the simplecv dist there is a requirements doc which lists:

```
SimpleCV

 pygame>=1.9.1 
 PIL==1.1.7 
 nose>=1.0.0 
 ipython>=0.12 
 numpy>=numpy-2.0.0
```

Is that numpy 2.0? IN the errors below a numpy-1.9 is listed. **I have only numpy-1.8 and if I go to [source forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/) for the latest version for OSX, it is numpy-1.8.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.whl**

So is that the problem I am having then, a numpy versioning issue?

*(Ironic that installing simplecv seems to be so hard. Thanks for reading this far, if you did...)*

```
bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin


bash-3.2$ simplecv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/simplecv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('SimpleCV==1.3', 'console_scripts', 'simplecv')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2321, in load_entry_point
    except ValueError:
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2048, in load

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SimpleCV-1.3-py2.7.egg/SimpleCV/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from SimpleCV.base import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SimpleCV-1.3-py2.7.egg/SimpleCV/base.py", line 22, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_7cefb25-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/__init__.py", line 159, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
ImportError: cannot import name add_newdocs
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (I don't do SimpleCV), but a couple of things to check:

(added) numpy>=numpy-2.0.0 is clearly wrong; patch that, or tell brew to use 1.8.

You're on 10.8.5, but the last couple of error lines have ...macosx-10.9 ?? (maybe a red herring)

If you just `import numpy`, what's `numpy.__version__` ?

numpy 1.8.0 has `218484 30 Oct 19:32 numpy/add_newdocs.py` at top level;
do you have that file somewhere, can you just copy it over ?

Comment: hey thanks - I saw the OSX 10.9 reference too and wondered if that was it. Going to upgrade my OS and try again.